On Thue-Siegel-Roth Theorem.
Let us take a number $\sqrt{2}$. Suppose we are given a certain $\epsilon > 0$. Consider the inequality
$$
|\sqrt{2} - \frac{q}{p}| < \frac{1}{p^{2+\epsilon}} \quad \cdots \quad  (\lozenge)
$$
with $p, q \in {\Bbb N}$. We will immedietaly see that
$$
-\frac{1}{p^{2+\epsilon}} < \sqrt{2} - \frac{q}{p},
$$
which yields the inequality
$$
\sqrt{2} + \frac{q}{p} < 2\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{p^{2+\epsilon}}.
$$
However, $p \geq 2$ ensures the following result$\colon$
$$
\sqrt{2} + \frac{q}{p} < 2\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2+\epsilon}} = C(\epsilon). \quad \cdots \quad  (\blacklozenge)
$$
Multiplying $(\lozenge)$ and $(\blacklozenge)$, we finally obtain
$$
|2 - \frac{q^2}{p^2}| < \frac{C(\epsilon)}{p^{2 + \epsilon}},
$$
from which we get
$$
1 \leq |2p^2 - q^2| < \frac{C(\epsilon)}{p^{\epsilon}}. \quad \cdots \quad (\sharp)
$$
This gives us the upper bound of the denominator $p$ as follows$\colon$
$$
p < C(\epsilon)^{1/\epsilon}.
$$
Also once $p$ is fixed, $q$ is also determined by $(\sharp)$ among finitely many possibilities. Putting these all together, the inequality $(\lozenge)$ has only finitely many solutions.
Q. Is this proof available only for quadratics?
I would like to know if there is any similarity between the above observation and Roth's proof which treat the general algebraic irrational numbers.

You can do something very similar for general algebraic numbers and show that their irrationality measure is bounded above by their degree. Roth’s theorem is much more difficult.


Is this proof only available for quadratics?

Yes.
In general, the following is true, and follows from an argument not so different from yours:

Lemma: If $\alpha$ is an irrational root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n > 1$ with integer coefficients, then there exists a real number $A > 0$ such that for all integers $p, q$ with $q > 0$,
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{A}{q^n}$$

However, the proof of Siegel's exponent ($\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{A}{q^{\sqrt{n} + \varepsilon}}$) is much more technical than this. The proof of Roth's exponent ($\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{A}{q^{2 + \varepsilon}}$) is even more technical than Siegel's. I don't know the proof of Thue's exponent, but I expect the proof of this is also significantly more complicated than the proof of the above lemma.
The argument you have given has very little similarity with the proof of Thue-Siegel-Roth, because if you try to run the proof in greater generality, you will find that the best you can manage with this method is the result of the above Lemma; improving the exponent requires a significantly different method, and quite a bit of care.
For a proof of the above Lemma and some related material, you should research "Liouville's number".

Thanks a lot. After all, Siegel's argument should be more lofty and transcendental than what I learned. I will try to read it!
